# How to write ecto code with nested relation

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have following DB table relation.

`Prefecture` 1 - 1 `Member` 1 - N `MemberAction`

I would like to get data, in case of SQL.

```
    SELECT A.action, M.member_name, 
      FROM MemberAction A
      JOIN Member M 
        ON M.id = A.member_id
      JOIN Prefecture P
        ON M.prefecture_id = P.id
```

However I have no idea to write code by Ecto.
Following code does not work. Because of `MemberAction does not have association`

```
    query = from a in MemberAction,
            where: a.id == ^action_id,
            preload: [:member, :prefecture]
    Repo.all(query)
```

Please give me some advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you define your schemas? Make sure they are similar to the following:

```elixir
defmodule YourApp.Schema.Prefecture do
  use Ecto.Schema
  schema "prefectures" do
    # your fields
  
    has_one(:member)
  end
end

defmodule YourApp.Schema.Member do
  use Ecto.Schema
  schema "members" do
    # your fields
  
    belongs_to(:prefecture)
    has_many(:member_actions)
  end
end

defmodule YourApp.Schema.MemberAction do
  use Ecto.Schema
  schema "member_actions" do
    # your fields
  
    belongs_to(:member)
  end
end
```

And then you should be able to use a query that's very similar to yours

```elixit
    query = from a in MemberAction,
            where: a.id == ^action_id,
            preload: [member: :prefecture]
    Repo.all(query)
```

Comment: I don't understand part of 'preload: [member: :prefecture]'

Comment: It loads a nested association in this case. `:prefecture` is not a direct association of `MemberAction`, so you'll need to preload it through a direct association, which is `:member`. That is what the `preload: [member: :prefecture]` part do.
You could find out more about `Ecto.Query.preload` from the documentation https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Ecto.Query.join/5`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html?#join/5).

```rb
query = from a in MemberAction,
  join: m in Member,
  on: [id: a.member_id]
  join: p in Prefecture,
  on: [id: m.prefecture_id],
  select: {a.action, m.member_name}
```